# What is the purpose of CustomURLs in Force.com sites

Tags: force.com-sites

Could some one please tell me what is the purpose of Custom URLs in Force.com site and when was it released.
Great if some one could brief with an example on how to use this CustomURLs feature. Could not find it over help page.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our domain is [centerpointenergy.force.com](http://centerpointenergy.force.com).  Going there will take you the site.

But we have a custom URL of [mytruecost.com](http://www.mytruecost.com), because it's easier for customers to remember and describes what the site offers rather than what company made it and the company that hosts it.

It also helps that each of our sites can have different URLs rather than centerpointenergy.force.com/something.

It's been around for at least 4 years.

Answer (score 1):

Custom urls are used to create relationship between domain and Sites. They are used to handle multiple sites from single domain name and multiple domain names. If your domain is `www.mydomain.com` which opens "site1" then by creating new custom url you can provide access to "site2" by same domain but different url path e.g; `www.mydomain.com/custompath` will open different site.

You can read more about it [here](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=domain_mgmt_overview.htm&siteLang=en_US)